# TCPDF set different headers for different pages in one document

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Is there a way to have a different header logo for the 1st page in a document and different for the 2nd page?

I thought that changing the header data between adding pages might do the trick, but in my tests it seems that setting the header after adding the first page has no effect:

```
/* other stuff
$pdf->setHeaderFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
*/

$pdf->SetHeaderData("logo_1.png", PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, '', '');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($htmlContent, true, 0, true, true);

$pdf->SetHeaderData("logo_2.png", PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, '', '');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($htmlContent2, true, 0, true, true);
```

The above produces a document with 2 pages, both having `logo_1.png` in header.

Will I need to customize TCPDF itself? Has anyone done this? I'm using version `5.9.144`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strange.  I'm having the same issue, but this worked in my older version of TCPDF version:4.8.009 and I noticed the issue when I upgraded to 5.9.149.

I compared the 2 and isolated the issue to the Header() function.

I could force it to allow me to change the header and accept it by running this:

```
$pdf->setHeaderTemplateAutoreset(true);
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was after

Comment: It is not working in TCPDF Version: 6.0.084. Do you know that about it?

Comment: seems not working with 6.3 either

Answer (score 9):

The following worked for me,

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF{
    function header1(){
        //print whatever the header 1 is
    }
    function Header2(){         
        if($this->page==1){
            //print header 1 and whatever the header 2 is
        }else{
            //print just header 2   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used:

```
$pdf->resetHeaderTemplate();
```

It should override the template header and assign the new one according to need. It worked for me.

Comment: How to add new content for that header?

Comment: worked for me with version 6.3, `$pdf->resetHeaderTemplate();$pPdf->SetHeaderData('pdf_header_p2.jpg', 180, "", "");$pPdf->AddPage();`

Answer (score 1):

How about... have TCPDF generate pages with different headers as separate documents, and then use something to merge all those intermediate PDFs together to form the final document's pages (maybe even TCPDF itself can merge, I don't know)?

A couple of "how to merge?" results:

- [Merge PDF files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php)
- [Merge files into a single PDF using PHP/linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056415/merge-files-into-a-single-pdf-using-php-linux)

Comment: I'm using Zend Framework for the project so merging was easy to do with `Zend_Pdf`. I'll post the relevant code as a separate answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for taking away some reputation, the other solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a cover page without header and footer and internal pages with them, there is an easier way to handle it.
Simply turn off the header and footer print via 'setPrintHeader' and 'setPrintFooter' as follows:

```
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("freesans", "B", 20);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"COVER TEXT",1,1,'C');

$pdf->setPrintHeader(true);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(true);

$pdf->setHeaderFont(array("freesans", "", 9));
$pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', 'Document Title', 'Document Header Text');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("freesans", "B", 20);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Internal text",1,1,'C');

$pdf->Output("HappyCover.pdf", "I");
```

Enjoy!

Comment: The question is how to add a different logo in the header, not get rid of the header all-together.

Comment: The right solution is what Joaquin suggested, overwriting the Header() and Footer() methods.

Comment: I downvoted it because it showed footer in the cover page. Please enable footer and header AFTER you create a second page, i.e. after `$pdf->AddPage()`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, if someone has the same problem in the future and can use `Zend_Pdf`:

```
// $filename is the final filename with path to save the generated PDF
$dir = dirname($filename);
$base = basename($filename);

$page1 = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "tmp_1_" . $base;
$page2 = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "tmp_2_" . $base;

//creates 1st page with TCPDF and saves to filesystem with filename $page1
$this->generateInvoicePage1($html_1, $page1);

//creates 2nd page with TCPDF and saves to filesystem with filename $page2
$this->generateInvoicePage2($html_2, $page2);

$pdf1 = Zend_Pdf::load($page1);
$pdf2 = Zend_Pdf::load($page2);

foreach ($pdf2->pages as $page) {
    $pdf1->pages[] = clone($page);
}

$pdf1->save($filename);

unlink($page1);
unlink($page2);
```

Comment: Also, performance-wise, this seems to be quite a bit slower than generating one document with one library, so beware.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the solution with the lightest touch:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function AddNewHeader($newTitle) {
        $this->header_xobj_autoreset = true;
        $this->header_title = $newTitle;
    }

}
```

Be sure to call TCPDF::setHeaderData() first.  Next, call this function before every AddPage() event, or, if you're looping through data and relying on tcpdf to add pages, call it after every element add.  It breaks the caching of the header, but allows the user to put a new and custom header on each page.  All the elements returned by TCPDF::getHeaderData() can be updated in this way.

Answer (score 0):

my solution, with just a condition

```
 function Header(){
    if($this->page==1){
       $html = '<div><img src="./outils/img1.png" alt=""></div>';
        $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
    }else{
        $html = '<div><img src="./outils/img2.png" alt=""></div>';
        $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer please, for example what is new compared to the already existing  answers?