# How to add header align right in TCPDF file

Tags: codeigniter, pdf-generation, codeigniter-2, tcpdf

I need to add HEADER data with the TCPDF(in codeigniter).
like:

```
HEADING_TEXT_LEFT                                           HEADING_TEXT_RIGHT
______________________________________________________________________________
```

This type of heading for Left and right I need to add, with two different Text. Also I cannot change the header() function as I am using PDF in several places. So I don't need common place, solution is for this. Is there any way to make this.

I am using this :
`$this->pdf->SetHeaderData("", "", "", $left_header_text);`
but this will give only one variable and that is also left side.

Comment: follow the below link
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/

Comment: It is updating header function, but I am using it so many places, so I need specific solution.

Comment: $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **Arturo** answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495688/how-to-put-html-data-into-header-of-tcpdf), this should work fine for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.